Control de errores de WebService JAX-WS en Java 8
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Java versión 8 el cual será un Webservice en SOAP para descargar mensajes en un pdf.
Éste es el parámetro de entrada en SOAP:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pal="http://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pal:DescargaMensajesEntidades>
         </pal:DescargaMensajesEntidades>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Y éste el de salida:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <dlwmin:DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse xmlns:dlwmin="http://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
         <out xmlns:a="http://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet">El proceso se ha ejecutado correctamente con 1 descarga(s)</out>
      </dlwmin:DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

Los parámetros de salida se guardan en la siguente clase:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "out"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse")
public class DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String out;

   //metodos getter y setter

}

Él proceso se ejecuta mediante el siguiente metodo:
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="es.xxxxx.palexws.ws.PALEXWS", targetNamespace="http://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet", serviceName="PALEXWS", portName="PALEXWS")
public class PALEXWSSoapBindingImpl{

    public String descargaMensajesEntidades() {
        // TODO Apéndice de método generado automáticamente
        String respuesta = "";
        try {
            DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse response = new DescargaMensajesEntidadesResponse();
            DescargarMensajesEntidadesService descargarMensajesEntidadesService = new DescargarMensajesEntidadesServiceImpl();
            response = descargarMensajesEntidadesService.ejecutar();
            respuesta = response.getOut();
        } catch (DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception e) {
            // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
            e.printStackTrace();
            respuesta = e.getMessage();
        }
        
        return respuesta;
    }

}

Me gustaría saber en caso de que falle mi aplicación (Time Out, servidor caído, etc..) que en Soap  se muestre su fallo.
Éstas son las clases creadas para demostrar el fallo pero no sé cómo desarrollarlo en el método:
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "message"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault")
public class DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault {

    protected String message;

    //metodos getter y setter

}

@WebFault(name = "DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault", targetNamespace = "http://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet")
public class DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception
    extends Exception
{

    /**
     * Java type that goes as soapenv:Fault detail element.
     * 
     */
    private DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault faultInfo;

    /**
     * 
     * @param faultInfo
     * @param message
     */
    public DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception(String message, DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param faultInfo
     * @param message
     * @param cause
     */
    public DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault_Exception(String message, DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault faultInfo, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return
     *     returns fault bean: lexnet.webservices.wslexnet.DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault
     */
    public DescargaMensajesEntidadesFault getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }

Muchas gracias
